# Function runs on CLI but not from bash script

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, executable

I made a bash script to generate an ssh that I use all the time with a couple options.  At the end it echos a string for whatever it is going to execute, and then it executes it.  Currently I'm trying to add the functionality to add in a bash command to run once the ssh is completed, but its giving an error like so:

```
bash: /bin/echo 'hello'; bash -l: No such file or directory
```

Yet if I copy the command it runs, and run it from outside the executable, it runs perfectly.  Is there any reason I would be getting this error from inside the executable, and not from the CLI?

An example command it generates is:

```
pair -c "/bin/echo 'hello'"
Running: ssh ****@#.#.#.# -p443 -t "/bin/echo 'hello'; bash -l"
```

Comment: What is the exact command that creates the error? Or at least show us the part of the script that generates and calls the command.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused because of too strong quoting. This error line

```
bash: /bin/echo 'hello'; bash -l: No such file or directory
```

shows that bash does not try to execute the command `/bin/echo` with the argument `'hello'` followed by the command `bash -l`. Instead bash is trying to execute the command `/bin/echo 'hello'; bash -l`.

Compare:

```
$ ssh localhost -t "/bin/echo 'foo'; bash -l"
foo
$ logout # this is the new shell
Connection to localhost closed.
```

and:

```
$ ssh localhost -t '"/bin/echo 'foo'; bash -l"'
bash: /bin/echo foo; bash -l: No such file or directory
Connection to localhost closed.
```

The solution to this problem usually involves `eval`, but I cannot tell for sure unless I see more code from you.